# MediaElement.js stop autoplay in a page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mediaelement.js

I use mejsaudio in my wordpress site header. I use it with this code;

```
[mejsaudio src="http://specialholidayinturkey.org/special-fon.mp3" volume="1" autoplay="true" loop="true"]
```

so it starts in everypage in my site.

But I want to stop it in my video page. I need a java code to stop it i think.

Pls help me.

Comment: If you want to disable autoplay, you could try this: autoplay="false".
Or do you want it to autoplay but stop it with a stop-button?

Answer (score 0):

Try the native HTML5 method to pause:

```
$('#myAudioElement').pause();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code

```
<script>
function aud_play_pause() {
  var myAudio = document.getElementById("wp_mep_1");
  if (myAudio.play) {
    myAudio.pause();
  } else {
    myAudio.pause();
  }
}
</script>
<body onLoad="aud_play_pause()">
```

thanks for your answer. "wp_mep_1" is my audio id that i saw in my source code of web site.